# Recommended way to draw sets in Euclidean plane

Tags: pgfplots, tkz-euclide

I was wondering which is the most appropriate tool to draw sets in the Euclidean plane (with axis) such as the plane minus a given ray or the points in the plane which have a y coordinate between 2 and 3 . I was about to use `pgf plots` but that doesn't allow me to shade so freely the given regions (specially in the case of the whole plane minus a couple of points or lines), then I read about `tkz-euclide` but I have no clue how to use that one. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) to draw some of the regions mentioned (the region bounded by two horizontal straight lines, the region outside a horizontal strip, the plane minus some rays, the plane minus some points):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,varwidth=true,varwidth=40cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-1,
ymax=4
]
\addplot[name path=line1,dashed] {3};
\addplot[name path=line2,dashed] {2};
\addplot[cyan!30]   fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3
]
\addplot[name path=line1,draw=none] {3};
\addplot[name path=line2,draw=none] {-3};
\addplot[name path=line3,dashed] {1};
\addplot[name path=line4,dashed] {-1};
\addplot[brown!30]   fill between[of=line1 and line3];
\addplot[brown!30]   fill between[of=line2 and line4];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3
]
\addplot[name path=line1,draw=none] {3};
\addplot[name path=line2,draw=none] {-3};
\addplot[orange!30]   fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\draw[fill=white]
  (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=3pt];
\draw[double,double distance=2pt]
  ([shift={(0:2.7pt)}]axis cs:0,0) -- ++(0:30cm);
\draw[double,double distance=2pt]
  ([shift={(135:2.7pt)}]axis cs:0,0) -- ++(135:30cm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3
]
\addplot[name path=line1,draw=none] {3};
\addplot[name path=line2,draw=none] {-3};
\addplot[magenta!30]   fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\draw[fill=white]
  (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=3pt];
\draw[fill=white]
  (axis cs:-2,2) circle [radius=3pt];
\draw[fill=white]
  (axis cs:1,-1.7) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use GeoGebra to make the drawing manually and I can export the tikz code.

If you are using Ubuntu, install GeoGebra from the terminal by running

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install geogebra`

Or download from https://www.geogebra.org/download?lang=en

- **Ubuntu**: File --> Export --> Graphics View as PGF/TikZ
  [image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

- **Mac/Windows**: Collapsed menu icon --> Download as --> PGF/TikZ
  [image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Thanks.

Comment: Since the OP didn't mention which operating system they were using, I don't think this constitutes a very useful answer. It'd be more practical to provide a [link to Geogebra's site](https://www.geogebra.org/).

Comment: Thank you, @Miyase. I've added the link to my answer.